# Environment Variables for static site?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, google-cloud-storage, static-site, google-secret-manager

I'm considering deploying a React app as a static site, to cloud storage bucket.

There're some api keys are needed for the app but I could not find a way to set environment variables in cloud storage.

Is it even possible to use environment variables in cloud storage?

GCP Secret Manager may be an option, but looks like it's for server side. And it requires auth but my main purpose of using environment variables is to store Firebase keys used in firebase authentication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, Cloud Storage does not have a way to set envvars for statically served files. It’s a little weird, but you’re expected to put that API key in plaintext in the HTML/JavaScript for firebase.

Comment: You can add it in your code at the packaging step. But, be careful, you will share an API key to anyone. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

You could host your static site on Cloud Storage but that doesn't allow you to set environment variables on it.

As an alternative you could use App Engine Standard and deploy your static site there. In the `app.yaml` you will [be able to do so](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables):

> **Optional**. You can define environment variables in your app.yaml file
> to make them available to your app.
>
> Environment variables that are prefixed with GAE are reserved for
> system use and not allowed in the app.yaml file.
>
> > Example:
> >
> > `env_variables:   MY_VAR: "my value"`
>
> where `MY_VAR` and `my value` are the name and value of the environment
> variable that you want to define and each environment variable entry
> is indented two spaces under the `env_variables` element.